# If I have an autonomous propeller drone flying above the oceans, what is the best/cheapest satellite phone I could use to take pictures and send data?

Tags: long-range-drone

If I wanted it to take pictures every so often and give its position and other data like temperature on a twitter account. I assume I have to use a satellite phone. What is the cheapest/best worldwide satellite phone to use?

Comment: I don't think this is really within the scope of the site; even if it is, you're going to have to be way more specific - "cheapest/best" could have a thousand different answers; best for what?  What are your specifications?  What exactly is your project? How are you planning on sending the data?  What kind of drone are you using? Etc.

Comment: Drone is home built but will be solar powered.  Project not important  I think the only way to send data is through satellite phone, right?  best/cheapest means a very good phone that doesn't cost a lot of money.

Comment: You need a satellite modem of some sorts, which is a part of a satellite phone. Pull apart the phone, and figure out the protocols, you'll have to reverse engineer some of the stack, and then tap into twitter's APIs (do this on a remote groundstation). Note - making something that flies indefinitely with solar power is _not easy_ and some may argue borderline impossible

Comment: Yes, I know it will be difficult and I will not be attempting it alone.  It is a class project.  Different people working on different parts of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose a network first. Equipment is not interchangeable between networks. Have you considered uploads only. I believe there is at least one provider who offers this service. May be lighter in terms of weight and cheaper in terms of operational costs. For normal bidirectional communication there is plenty of options.  A quick search on Iridium revealed they have some small modules. Not cheap this stuff. You're easily looking at a 1,000USD for Sat equipment. Service is also not cheap. I am not aware of cheaper OEM alternatives, but that does not mean that they do not exist. A off-the-shelf module approach would greatly simplify the engineering. If in your class (including teacher?) you have the know-how to use an old phone and hack into that you may be able to save quite a bit of money and buy a second hand phone. Else, I think an Iridium Core could be the way to go. They go for 750USD and weigh only 32g

Since it is a school project, you could consider approaching such a provider and ask for some sort of sponsorship. This may save you in terms of both money and time. They could also be able to offer you some technical assistance. Every company deals with such requests differently, but I would be open to such requests.

Joey